# How can I convert these for loops to while loops?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

Sorry, a very noob question here (I'm new to python).Can someone please help me convert all for loops in this program to while loops in python? I can't really figure out how. Thank you!

```
while True:
word=str(input("Enter a string up to 10 characters: "))
y=0
z=len(word)
while (y<len(word)and y<10):
   print(" "*z,end='')
   for x in range(0,y):
       print(word[x],end='')
   for x in range (y,-1,-1):
       print(word[x],end='')
   y+=1
   z-=1
   print("")
y-=1
z+=1
while(y>0):
    y-=1
    z+=1
    print(" "*z,end='')
    for x in range(0,y):
         print(word[x],end='')
    for x in range(y,-1,-1):
       print(word[x],end='')
    print("")
```

Comment: But why do you want to convert them to while loops? For a homework exercise?

Comment: Yes. It was for an assignment but I only managed to do it using for loops. The exercise asks for while loops.

Comment: Make sure you fully understand how both of them work (which is the point of this homework problem), and show what code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mechanical transformation. Starting from

```
for name in iterable:
    body
```

You have

```
_name = iter(iterable)
try:
    while True:
        name = next(_name)
        body
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

However you don't need those for loops.

```
print(" " * (10 - y), word[:y], word[:y:-1], sep="")
```

Comment: Not saying that this answer isn't correct, but given that OP is a beginner, their original homework problem probably expects a more "intuitive" solution with C-like loop variables and conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In general terms:

```
for x in range(a,b,c):
    ... your code ...
```

converts to:

```
x = a
while x < b:             # if c is negative, use while x > b: instead
    ... your code ...
    x += c
```

knowing that:

`range(a,b)` is the same as `range(a,b,1)`

`range(b)`   is the same as `range(0,b,1)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late on the answer...

```
while True:
    word=str(input("Enter a string up to 10 characters: "))
    y=0
    z=len(word)
    while (y<len(word)and y<10):
       print(" "*z,end='')
       x=0
       while x<y:
           print(word[x],end='')
           x+=1
       x=y
       while x != -1:
           print(word[x],end='')
           x-=1
       y+=1
       z-=1
       print("")
    y-=1
    z+=1
    while(y>0):
        y-=1
        z+=1
        print(" "*z,end='')
        x=0
        while x<y:
            print(word[x],end='')
            x+=1
        x=y
        while x!=-1:
            x-=1
            print(word[x],end='')
        print("")
```